# Saving Raster3D as transparent PNG

Tags: graphics3d, png-format

I am trying to save a `Raster3D` object to a transparent .PNG. The background should be transparent while the cube has full opacity. Setting `Background -> None` doesn't seem to have the desired effect. The background is always white if I proceed as follows:

```
img = Graphics3D[{Raster3D[RandomReal[1, {8, 8, 8, 3}]]}, Boxed -> False, Background -> None]
Export["cube.png", img];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this; think it might be what you need:

```
    img = Rasterize[Graphics3D[{Raster3D[RandomReal[1, {8, 8, 8, 3}]]}, Boxed -> False],"Image", Background -> None]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me unfortunately.

Comment: @LennartVanderGoten why don't you tell us _why_ it doesn't work? Like what errors messages you get, for example. Saying it doesn't work without any explanation isn't helpful. This answer worked for me and `Export["cube.png", img]` produced an image with an alpha channel.

Comment: My fault, I used a wrong image viewer which filled the background with white. Answer accepted!